# How to add elements dynamically in a 2d list from another list in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, 2d

I have a list of model class objects. Such as -

```
List<ModelChannel> allChannels = [];
```

I have added elements in this list from json. Model Class variables are-

```
final String channelid;
final String channelname;
final String channeltype;
final String categoryname;
final String channelimage;
final String channelurl;
```

Here categorytype contains country information. I want to divide the list country wise dynamically. I have intended to use 2d list where each row will contain all the channels of a specific country. Is this the right approach? If yes how to implement this and if not what will be the right one?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) function from [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package.

Add this package to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  collection: any
```

And use `groupBy`:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

...

final groupByCountry = groupBy(allChannels, (ModelChannel e) => e.categoryname);
```

Comment: The package you provided might do the work. But I have done it with my own logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<ModelChannel>> countryList = [];
List<String> channelType = [];

allChannels.forEach((element) {

    if (channelType.isEmpty) {
      channelType.add(element.channeltype);
    } else {
      if (channelType.contains(element.channeltype)) {
      } else {
        channelType.add(element.channeltype);
      }
    }
  });

  channelType.forEach((countryCode) {
    List<ModelChannel> t = [];
    allChannels.forEach((element) {
      if (element.channeltype == countryCode) {
        t.add(element);
      }
    });
    countryList.add(t);
  });
```